# How to provide navigation controller to DetailViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have added a table view in the detailView (splitViewController) controller. Can anyone tell me how to puch other views using this table view? Its not working with me.

Answer (score 0):

in your tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath method you can push view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        Otherview *otherview=[[Otherview alloc]initWithNibName:@"Otherview" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherview animated:YES];
         [otherview relese]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil;

}
```